# Actionscript: Playing sound from microphone on speakers (through buffer) with constant delay

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio, actionscript, signal-processing

I'm looking for an example of code that samples signal from microphone and
plays it on speakers. I need a solution that has a resonably constant delay on
different platforms (PC, android, iphone). Delay around 1-2 s is ok for me, and I don't
mind if it varies everytime the application starts.

I tried using SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA event on Sound and Microphpne classess.
One event would put data into buffer the other would read data.
But it seems impossible to provide constant delay, either the delay grows constantly or
it gets lower to the point where I have less than 2048 samples to put out and Sound class stops
generating SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA events.

I wan't to process each incoming frame so using setLoopBack(true) is not an option.

ps This is more a problem on Android devices than on PC. Althought when I start to resize application
window on PC delay starts to grow also.

Please help.

Comment: I think that delay can change during application runtime, but whats importand is that it should be stable within some limits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this won't be possible... at least not directly.

Some sound devices will use a different clock between recording and playback.  This will be especially true for cell phones where what is running the microphone may very well be different hardware than the headphone audio output.

Basically, if you record at 44.1kHz and play back at 44.1kHz, but those clocks are not in sync, you may be recording at 44.099kHz and play back at 44.101kHz.  Over time, this drift will mean that you won't have enough data in the buffer to send to the output.

Another complication (and more than likely your problem) is that your record and playback sample rates may be different.  If you record from the microphone at 11kHz and playback at 48kHz, you will note that 11 doesn't evenly fit into 48.  Software is often used to up-sample the recording.  Sometimes this is done with a nice algorithm which is guaranteed to give you the necessary output.  Other times, that 11kHz will get pushed to 44kHz and is deemed "close enough".

In short, you cannot rely on recording and playback devices being in sync, and will need to synchronize yourself.  There are many algorithms out there for handling this.  The easiest method is to add a sample here and there that averages the sample before and after it.  If you do this with just a few samples, it will be inaudible.  Depending on the kind of drift problem you are having, this may be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for Help. Its good to know that those clocks may have different speeds.  I'm sampling mic. signal at 44.1 khz, and AFAIK output of AIR apps i also 44.1khz. But i think that my issue is somehow different. It probably has to do with the way flash executes events in a single thread. It is very easy to increase lag just by resizing application window wchich i think causes lots of other events.

Comment: I even tried to monitor in what order input and output events are called. In normal conditions most of the time they are alternating IOIO.. But if I simulate more load only input event is called for a while, which I think causes the increase in lag. I'm wondering can this be prevented. I don't mind loosing input frames.

Comment: Hmm, when you cause load, I assume the output stops or glitches for a brief moment?

Comment: Havent noticed that, probably there were still some data in the buffer outside of my app. Or maybe the sound from microphone i so repetitive that it all sounded the same to me. I could see that only input event was triggered. Maybe flash events have some priorities that can be changed ? :-)

Comment: It's likely there isn't much you can do, but let's be sure of the problem first.  If the output truly stopped, you would hear it.  Plug something into the audio input of your computer that plays something continuous but varying, like music.  When the output can't keep up, it will either go silent (software buffer under-run) or play in a short loop (hardware buffer under-run).

Comment: I was able to fix the problem simply by droping an incoming frame when delay gets to big. Earlier I tried to push more data out of the buffer. Which I thnk caused flash to trigger output event less often. Which again caused more data to be stored in the buffer. Brad, thanks for help. Have a nice day :)